# Laravel Homestead - vm:The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Code on OSX Yosemite

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have brand new installation of laravel Homestead and my Homestead.yaml looks like this:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /srv/my_app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

When i try vagrant up: I get this error:

```
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Code
```

~/Code does not exists but it's specify to be other path in yaml file, seems like vagrant is keeping it somewhere in memory or something, any idea?

In case when I create ~/Code directory it works vagrant is up but code is not there because it sits on other location and mapping doesn't work at all, and I run into "No input file specified" issue which is obvious.

Comment: perhaps you're editing the wrong file, is this the `~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml`? That's the file most commonly used by homestead.

Comment: @Luceos  actually I edited Homestead.yaml from Homestead folder seems like part of it has been copied over on ~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml, is there a command which do flushing of it?

Comment: no you edit the file in your home.. Although i guess there should be a way to point to any other file. It seems that the path is hardcoded in the homestead executable.

Comment: did that and it works now, strange thing is in fact that it sits in ~/.homestead/.. not in vagrant VM folder...

Comment: found it confusing too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably were editing the wrong file.

After running init for homestead a local configuration file is created in your home directory under:

`~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml` you will need to apply changes there for them to take effect.